# Как вывести видео в Arduino?

Tags: arduino

Есть ли готовая библиотека для вывода видео потока с ip камеры и наложения текста на этот самый вывод. Нужна реализация подобного на C++ в arduino.

Comment: Врядли ардуино потянет обработку видео. Скорее всего вам нужно будет что-то вроде raspberry py.

Comment: Забудьте про ардуину с такими требованиями.

Comment: Может легче использовать Raspberry для этих целей